# How many types of Facebook updates?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook's Graph Api to get user's profile and home feed. Every feed item has a "type" field, e.g. type = video, type = status or type = link (these are the 3 types I could see from my feed).

Is there somewhere that lists other possible types? I am asking it because each type has different fields and I am having a difficulty to write a generic parser. E.g. type = "video" has fields like "descripton", "link" where type = "status" doesn't has. Currently my parser checks if the type is status or link, thus it parses those updates differently but I am afraid there are other types of updates which can break my application.

I looked at Facebook api page, but they don't seem to have a list of update types..

Answer (score 0):

i can suggest, make a list by yourself on every update types becouse facebook repairing to launch new app system now works on beta.facebook.com when this system applies to applications that types will be developer defined. they can come like type = recipe or type = music

better that keep a dynamic list for future types.